# How to get a minimum date from multiple identical rows and columns SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
ID  Type1   Type2     Created
---------------------------------------------
1    A        B       2014-01-25 00:34:32.630
1    A        B       2014-01-23 00:34:31.630
1    C        K       2014-01-22 00:34:30.630
1    Z        Y       2014-01-21 00:34:29.630
1    H        L       2014-01-20 00:34:28.630
1    H        L       2014-01-19 00:34:27.630
1    A        B       2014-01-18 00:34:26.630
```

As above. If the `ID`, `type1` and `type2` are the same, gave me the minimum created date but only if they are next to each other and no gaps.

This is how it should look like

```
ID  Type1   Type2     Created
---------------------------------------------
1    A        B       2014-01-23 00:34:31.630
1    C        K       2014-01-22 00:34:30.630
1    Z        Y       2014-01-21 00:34:29.630
1    H        L       2014-01-19 00:34:27.630
1    A        B       2014-01-18 00:34:26.630
```

Good luck and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Test data:

```
DECLARE @t table
(ID int, Type1 char(1), Type2 char(1), Created datetime)
INSERT @t values
(1,'A','B','2014-01-25 00:34:32.630'),
(1,'A','B','2014-01-23 00:34:31.630'),
(1,'C','K','2014-01-22 00:34:30.630'),
(1,'Z','Y','2014-01-21 00:34:29.630'),
(1,'H','L','2014-01-20 00:34:28.630'),
(1,'H','L','2014-01-19 00:34:27.630'),
(1,'A','B','2014-01-18 00:34:26.630')
```

Query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 
    ID, Type1, Type2, Created,
    dense_rank() over (order by Created) rn1,
    rank() over (partition by id, type1, type2 order by Created) rn2
  FROM @t
)
SELECT ID, Type1, Type2, min(Created) Created
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID, Type1, Type2, rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY Created
```

Result:

```
ID  Type1  Type2  Created
1   A      B      2014-01-18 00:34:26.630
1   H      L      2014-01-19 00:34:27.630
1   Z      Y      2014-01-21 00:34:29.630
1   C      K      2014-01-22 00:34:30.630
1   A      B      2014-01-23 00:34:31.630
```

Comment: The query won't work with multiple ID values. I think you want to change your `rn` expression to this: `row_number() over (partition by ID order by Created) rn`

Comment: @shawnt00 why not ? I include ID in group by, that should work just fine. I did make a different change to handle identical rows.

Comment: Well I have to read between the lines of the question to even presume that there are other ID values in this. But the problem in that case would be that if/when the Created dates from other IDs are interleaved it throws off the row numbering.

Comment: @shawnt00 I duplicated data in my example and used id 2 and 3. I got exactly the result i expected. Maybe it is the ordering that is confusing you

Comment: Changing to dense_rank helped mask the issue since you just duplicated the same Created values with the new ids. If you still care to check, then try bumping up the dates so they aren't ties in the ranking.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution will look something like this if you have a late enough version of SQL Server. One assumption is that there are never ties in the Created date within an ID. I'm also reading between the lines and assuming there there could be other ID values which need to be handled in isolation even if the dates overlap.

```
with T as (
    ID, Type1, Type2, Created
    select
        row_number() over (partition by ID order by Created) -
        -- row_number() over (order by ID, Created) /* should also work */
        row_number() over (partition by ID, Type1, Type2 order by Created) as Grp,
    from yourtable
)
select ID, Type1, Type2, min(Created)
from T
group by ID, Type1, Type2, Grp
```

Comment: Thank you gentlemen. I can now hand in my report and go home. Thank you once again

Comment: @Afrah were you really able to make this answer work ? That is very creative

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, I wasn't expecting anyone to give me a useful answer today, but thank you. your CTE has resolved the query and i have double check again and again and it is perfect